# Finding min elements index in array

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I can find min value index in my array. I found a lot of guides about it and I am doing the same, but my answer isn't correct.

```
    double minimum = main_array[0];
    int index_min;

    for (int i=1; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        if (main_array[i] < minimum)
            minimum = main_array[i];
            index_min = i;
}
```

The answer what I get is index of last element in the array, not the element with lowest value.

Comment: `if (main_array[i] < minimum)
            minimum = main_array[i];
            index_min = i;` => `if (main_array[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = main_array[i];
            index_min = i; }`

Comment: Use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)? It returns an iterator (which for arrays will be a pointer) but it's easy to get an index from that.

Comment: just need brackets for your `if` statement to include `index_min=i;`

Comment: @Satnam It helps to use a debugger to step through your code. That way you can find bugs like that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly wrap the if condition when you update index_min :

```
  if (main_array[i] < minimum) {
            minimum = main_array[i];
            index_min = i;
  }
```

Comment: Agreed. Reframed the answer language.

Comment: Okey, thanks I have a question about this. Why then I could find min value correct with that syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some brackets. Proper indention will help to see this. Currently your code looks like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
{
   if (main_array[i] < minimum)
       minimum = main_array[i]; // sets the minimum correctly
   index_min = i; // updates the index every run, resulting in index_min == ARRAY_SIZE -1
}
```

But you want this:

```
for (int i=1; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
{
   if (main_array[i] < minimum)
   {
       minimum = main_array[i]; 
       index_min = i; // only if a new minimum is found update the index_min variable 
    } // note the extra brackets ;-)
}
```

Also in C and C++ you usually use an extra line for eac curly bracket.